# Import .dmp file from 11g to 10g

Tags: oracle, import, oracle-dump

When i import .dmp file from 11g  to 10g,the log tip:

> IMP-00003:  ORACLE error 942
>
> ORA-00942: table or view not exists
>
> IMP-00017:  ORACLE error 20000, statement failed:
>
> "BEGIN
> DBMS_STATS.SET_TABLE_STATS(NULL,'"CQ_ANNUALPRJ"',NULL,NULL,NULL,141,"
> "5,123,6); END;"
>
> IMP-00003:  ORACLE error 20000
>
> ORA-20000: TABLE "ECA"."CQ_ANNUALPRJ" does not exist or insufficient
> privileges
>
> ORA-06512: on "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 2121
>
> ORA-06512: on "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 5975
>
> ORA-06512: on line 1

the imp state:

```
imp userid='ECA/CCIR@ORCL' file='E:\ecasys20130513empty\ecasys20130513empty.dmp' log='D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\orcl\ECASYS.log' full=y ignore=y;
```

I just change the version info: by open the dump file with notepad++, like this:

TEXPORT:V10.02.0

DECA

RUSERS

2048

0

64

0

TT?

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating an export dump file for an import into a lower release database you should use a version of the Export client that is equal to the version of the target database .

So in your case make sure you make the export dump file with a 10G version of the exp tool.

Comment: I just change the dmp file version info,source info was 11g,i just change it ro my version.Like this:TEXPORT:V10.02.0 
DECA
RUSERS
2048
0
64
0
TT?

Comment: The 11G export tool adds information to the dmp file that Oracle 10G does not understand. You have to re-create the dmp file from the original 11G database using the 10G client software.

Comment: I install the Oralce 11g,wish to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

that above error could be suppressed with statistics=none but the previous answers are correct, you have to use the correct export matching the version of the target to make it work correctly.